# How to handle form submission ASP.NET MVC Back button?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, back-button

i have a form which allows the user to key in the data and then submit.
if everything works well on this action result, then i will redirect the user back to a thank you page.

my problem right now is that when the user click on the back button, they will be able to go back to the form page and the inputs will still be there.

and if the user just click on submit again, i will be getting some potential weird bugs.

so in terms of asp.net mvc, what's the best way to handle users who click on the back button?

thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This solution works perfectly for both the whole controller or a specific action, simply add [NoCache]

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Prevent a controller or specific action from being cached in the web browser.
 /// For example - sign in, go to a secure page, sign out, click the back button.
 /// <seealso cref="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656476/mvc-back-button-issue/6656539#6656539"/>
 /// </summary>
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```
[NoCache]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Originally posted here: [MVC Back button issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656476/mvc-back-button-issue/6656539#6656539)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "potential weird bugs"? I doubt the user would click submit again unless they wanted to post exactly the same thing again. I you don't want duplicate posts, check the content against your DB before posting.

If you *really* don't want people posting the same form twice, put a randomly generated number (just make sure it's random enough to avoid collisions, or use something like a combination of the user ID and a precise timestamp) into a hidden field, save that with your data and check that it doesn't already exist in your DB before saving anything.

Comment: Since asp.net mvc is stateless I was just thinking maybe they have a new shebang method or best practice to handle this too.

Comment: I don't like when people claim some method is "the best practice".

Comment: lol true, but there's ugly hacks and then there's better tried and tested alternatives to use. i try to avoid the former as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FindResults", "COntrollerName", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "SearchForm" }))
{}
public ActionResult Index()
    {
return view();
}
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FindResults(FindIssueModel model)
    {
}
```