# The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the default login module in ASP.NET MVC 4. I did not change any code in the default application and i hosted it on a shared server.

After i logged in using default login page. i kept the browser idle for some time. Then obviously application redirected to the login page when i try to perform any controller action with   `[Authorize]` attribute.

Then i try to login again and it gives an error when i click on login button.

```
The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.
```

[image]

LogIn action

```
// POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Did you put the anti-forgery token into the form?

Comment: Could the shared host be messing with your cookies? `AntiForgeryToken` gives the visitor a cookie called `__RequestVerificationToken`, and also puts it in a hidden field on the page. When you call the server, it compares the value you have in your cookie and whatever was sent with the Form.

Comment: @ta.speot.is i haven't added it to the form since it's present in the controller. It need to be present at one of the places right? in the form or in the controller?

Comment: The attribute is called `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`. It `Validate`s the `AntiForgeryToken`...

Comment: @ta.speot.is sorry for my previous comment.  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() does exists in the form

Comment: Read this.May be helped to you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766975/requestverificationtoken-does-not-match and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767768/troubleshooting-anti-forgery-token-problems

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I resolved the issue by explicitly adding a machine key in web.config.

Note: For security reason don't use this key. Generate one from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218#AppendixA. Dont use online-one, details,  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/07/asp-net-4-5-2-and-enableviewstatemac.aspx

```
 <machineKey validationKey="971E32D270A381E2B5954ECB4762CE401D0DF1608CAC303D527FA3DB5D70FA77667B8CF3153CE1F17C3FAF7839733A77E44000B3D8229E6E58D0C954AC2E796B" decryptionKey="1D5375942DA2B2C949798F272D3026421DDBD231757CA12C794E68E9F8CECA71" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Here's a site that generates unique Machine Keys:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/

Comment: This solved the problem right away for me. Just as a note, this is placed inside the <system.web> tag in the web.config.

Comment: Hopefully that's not the actual machine key you placed in your application but instead you generated a new one :-)

Comment: hello .. i got the same problem as OP described. I tried this solution by getting one key from here http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey and doesn't fix the problem. Only difference is though, i don't always see this error. Only sometimes. Mine is on GoDaddy shared hosting. any thoughts?

Comment: As per [Microsoft's docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors#AppendixA) you should never use a 3rd party tool or website to generate machine keys. Always do it yourself.

Comment: You can generate them in IIS as well by clicking on any website, clicking on "Machine Key" under the "ASP.NET" section in the middle, then clicking on "Generate Keys" on the right.

Answer (score 11):

Another reason for having this error is if you are jumping between [Authorize] areas that are not cached by the browser (this would be done on purpose in order to block users from seeing protected content when they sign out and using the back button for example).

If that's case you can make your actions non cached, so if someone click the back button and ended up on a form with @Html.AntiForgeryToken() the token will not be cached from before.

See this post for how to add [NoCache] ActionFilterAttribute: 
[How to handle form submission ASP.NET MVC Back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628183/how-to-handle-form-submission-asp-net-mvc-back-button/30964024#30964024)

Comment: Scanner, you're missing the point here, Ctrl+F5 does clear the cache, but internet users will not know that they need to do that, plus it shouldn't happen anyways.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you put the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your page's form

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for a long time and assumed it was something wrong with ASP.NET.

In reality, it was the server. I was with WinHost then, and they have a 200MB memory limit. As soon as I had ~20 users on at the same time, my limit was reached. At this point, everyone was logged out and yielded these issues.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this was caused by submitting a form using a button tag. Changing this to     an input submit tag resolves the issue.

Comment: Mike's suggestion above, plus the hard machinekey did the trick for me. I was getting this consistently while debugging an MVC4 app with user/pass login.

Comment: @Mike - why does the button tag cause this issue but not an input tag?

Answer (score 0):

In My case "We found that the Site cache was enabled and due to this “anti-forgery” token value was not updating every time,  after removing this cache
form is submitting."

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to multiple cookie values set by domain site and subdomain site.

- main.com set __RequestVerificationToken = 1
- sub.main.com set __RequestVerificationToken = 2

but when request to sub.main.com was sent it used __RequestVerificationToken = 1 value from main.com