# ValidateAntiForgeryToken error on first run of application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

When i publish my application from my local development server to the shared hosting server i get an error the first time someone logs in.

```
Error in Controller Account, Action method Login. Exception: The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.
```

I've tried adding a machinekey but that didn't seem to make a difference. I am refreshing the login page prior to trying to login. Seems like the same issue as this

[The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097401/the-anti-forgery-cookie-token-and-form-field-token-do-not-match-in-mvc-4)

but the machine key didn't solve it. My application is ASP.Net 4.5.1 MVC5.1

Comment: You are only setting the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on the POST action method, right? From your description it sounds like the error is happening on a GET. Just making sure.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta its the code from the initial MVC5.1 template im using. but yes its on the accountcontroller login post action which has the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute. Yes the error is on posting login credentials (loggin in).