# MVC antiforgerytoken partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, antiforgerytoken

I have an MVC page with two partial views A and B. When I submit partial view B, ONLY the first time I get this error.

> The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.

After the first time the view works perfectly. I have added `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in the code page and have added `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the partial view.

When I remove the partial view A from the page, B is working without any error.

Any suggestion would really help.

Comment: Could you post the related section of code?  This may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097401/the-anti-forgery-cookie-token-and-form-field-token-do-not-match-in-mvc-4

Answer (score 3):

When you have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute the framework does the following

1. Check if incoming request has a cookie called `__RequestVerificationToken`
2. Check if incoming request has a `Request.Form` entry called `__RequestVerificationToken`
3. Check if cookie and `Request.Form` values match

Because of the above process, one page can only have one valid AntiForgery token.

For details check http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/