# "The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match" on page with ViewModel and two forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, antiforgerytoken

In a MVC4 app running on Mono I get the error:

> The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match

on the "Login and Register" page. This page has a `LoginOrRegisterViewModel` which looks as follows:

```
public class LoginOrRegisterViewModel
{
    public LoginModel Login { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel Register { get; set; }
}
```

Which gets passed to the page on the GET request.

There are two `Html.BeginForms()` on the page, a `Login`-form and a `Register`-form. The first calls the `Login` action on the controller, the second the `Register` action. Both actions have a `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute. When a form is submitted the respectively `Login` or `Register` is obtained from the `LoginOrRegisterViewModel`.

When the page is loaded and a registered user tries to login after some tim (few hours?) the "Login and Register" page initially shows, but when the `Login` form is submitted the error above shows until the root page is refreshed.

I have included a Machine Key to the Web.config and have added `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to both forms. I have a suspicion this error might have to do with the two forms and the view model.

Does anyone know how the error can be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: Are you reseeding the db using Code First in the meantime and forgot to turn it off or something? That's a typical situation where the user is recreated in the database, making for a difference in anti-forgery token.

Comment: @WimOmbelets No the database is not reseeded. Only on registering the user is *created* (obviously).

Comment: Has the caller session expired during these few hours? AFAIK these tokens are stored in the session ... :)

Comment: @dna Should that matter? These types of application errors are not good for the user experience. For now I just removed the anti-forgery tokens.

Comment: Well if the session expires (with the anti forgery token in it) the verification of the token will obviously fails when the user post the form after that. I am not saying it's the cause of your error but it might be something worth looking into.

Comment: But @dna this happens on a new request of a previously logged who was logged out for a while. So when a user logs in after one day this exception is thrown. Is there a way to handle it properly?

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097401/the-anti-forgery-cookie-token-and-form-field-token-do-not-match-in-mvc-4/30972311#30972311

Answer (score 0):

MVC best coding standard, always practice with separation of code concern.

- Create two diffrent model 1 for LoginViewModel and 2 for Register View model.
- Create seperate partial view for both login and Register and Access via Partial Or RenderAction keyword.

If you are putting **@Html.AntiForgeryToken()** on your html form then, same way you need to validate anti-Forgery on Controller side method by writing attribute **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]** .

Html helper will generate unique token inside your form like,

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="4dvPVQIvpXNEKZyV1DCjeN1rmtMDJ9fQ2">
```

For each of the form unique Anti-forgery token will be generate and, it will resolve your confliction.

Let me know in case is you still facing difficulty.