# The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies, antiforgerytoken

My website is raising this exception around 20 times a day, usually the form works fine but there are instances where this issue occur and I don't know why is so random.

This is logged exception by elmah

> 500   HttpAntiForgery The required anti-forgery cookie __RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

But the form it is sending the the token as shown on the XML log by elmah

```
<form>
    <item name="__RequestVerificationToken">
      <value string="DNbDMrzHmy37GPS6IFH-EmcIh4fJ2laezIrIEev5f4vOhsY9T7SkH9-1b7GPjm92CTFtb4dGqSe2SSYrlWSNEQG1MUlNyiLP1wtYli8bIh41"/>
    </item>
    <item name="toPhone">
      <value string="XXXXXX"/>
    </item>
    <item name="smsMessage">
      <value string="xxxxxxxx"/>
    </item>
</form>
```

This is my method on the controller which uses the data Attribute to check if the token is valid or nor

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<JsonResult> Send(SMSModel model)
{
    // my code goes here
}
```

This is my form on the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "SMS", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-sms", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">+53</div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.toPhone, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "teléfono", required = "required", type = "tel", maxlength = 8 })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="position:relative">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Message (up to 135 characters)</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.smsMessage, new { rows = 4, @class = "form-control", placeholder = "escriba aquí su mensaje", required = "required", maxlength = "135" })
        <span class="char-count">135</span>
    </div>
    if (ViewBag.Sent == true)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <strong>Su mensaje ha sido enviado <span class="hidden-xs">satisfactoriamente</span></strong>
        </div>
    }
    if (ViewBag.Error == true)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <strong>Error:</strong> Por favor revise el número de teléfono.
        </div>
    }
    <div class="errorToMany"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Enviar SMS</button>
}
```

And this how I post my data using AJAX

```
$('form.form-sms').submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            $('.btn-default').attr("disabled", true);
            $('.btn-default').html("Enviando...")
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data[0] == false && data[1] == "1") {
               some code 
            } else {
               location.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The form works well most time but this error keeps happening and I don't know why, I've checked other questions here on Stack Overflow but nothing works for me.

For further explanation about how I post the data.

This form to send SMS has the fields ToNumber and Message. When a user clicks on the submit Button the AJAX function takes control and post it serializing the form's field data, when my function in the controller finishes and return the JSON result indicating everything went well, the AJAX method reloads the page showing the user a success message.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It almost sounds as if things are working as expected.

The way the anti forgery helper  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` works is by injecting a hidden form field named `__RequestVerificationToken` into the page AND it also sets a cookie into the browser.

When the form is posted back the two are compared and if they don't match or the cookie is missing then the error is thrown.

So it does not matter that Elmah logs that the form is sending `__RequestVerificationToken`. It always will, even in the event of `CSRF` attack, because this is simply the hidden form field.

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="DNbDMrzHmy37GPS6IFH-EmcIh4fJ2laezIrIEev5f4vOhsY9T7SkH9-1b7GPjm92CTFtb4dGqSe2SSYrlWSNEQG1MUlNyiLP1wtYli8bIh41" />
```

The error message on the other hand says the corresponding `COOKIE` is not being sent:

> 500 HttpAntiForgery The required anti-forgery cookie
>   __RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

So basically someone/something is replaying the form post without making the original request to get the cookie. As such they have the hidden form field 
`__RequestVerificationToken` but NOT the cookie to verify it.

So it seems like things are working as they should. Check your logs re: IP numbers, and referrers, etc. You might be under attack or perhaps be doing something weird or buggy when redirecting your form content. As above, `referrers` are a good place to start for this kind of error, assuming this is not being spoofed.

Also note that as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

```
location.reload();
```

> The Location.reload() method reloads the resource from the current
>   URL. Its optional unique parameter is a Boolean, which, when it is
>   true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is
>   false or not specified, **the browser may reload the page from its
>   cache**.

If it is, on occasion loading from cache, then you might end up with a `POST` that has the old page token but not the cookie.

So try :

```
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Man, thank you for the detailed explanation, I didn't know the location.reload(true) trick. I just changed my code and will wait until tomorrow to see if don't receive this issue anymore and will mark your answer as accepted if that's the case.

Answer (score 31):

Ran into similar issue recently. 
The anti-forgery cookie indeed was missing, so (as others pointed out) either

1. the server did not add the cookie to request, or
2. the browser rejected it.

In my case, it was the server: I was not using SSL on local environment, yet in `web.config` I had the following line:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="True"/>
```

Solution in this case is to either switch to SSL, or keep the value set to 'False' for local environment.

Comment: In our case we had the issue when switching between localhost projects where some *were* SSL and some *were not* SSL

Comment: My XML validator gripes about `True`, to silence this, use lower case: `true`.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to rism's excellent answer, another possible reason for encountering this error is because **your browser, or browser plugin is blocking cookies from being set**.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in edge browser.

I have fixed this issue by changes browser setting.

Follow the instruction to fix the issue:

Go to Settings > View advanced settings > Cookies > Change to "Don't block cookies".

Close the browser and check.

I thought, it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at this question. [The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097401/the-anti-forgery-cookie-token-and-form-field-token-do-not-match-in-mvc-4)

It is possible that this is a timeout issue. Basically when the timeout happens the cookie is not stored because the iis user that the site is running under does not have the proper access. For me I changed the application pool to load the user profile and this seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

check whether are you miss this line in your front-end @Html.AntiForgeryToken() or not

Answer (score 0):

In my case it had to do with caching on IIS. 
I had to restart the entire IIS Server in Server manager.

Answer (score 0):

put the @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  inside your form

Answer (score 0):

Tried above solutions and still error exists. After checking further, it was due to browser settings I have used.

Do not use the option highlighted below. It causes cookies not to be stored. The reason why you get the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation using `http://ip-address`
I changed to `https://ip-address` and it worked.