# ASP.NET MVC antiforgery cookie error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, antiforgerytoken

Whenever an error is thrown in the try-catch block I want to return to the view and display to the user the error. This works fine when I run it on my local machine. However when I push onto the production server I get the error

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = @"Admin")]
    public ActionResult Post(CpjsProcessFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Password))
                {
                    _sysproCredentials.UserName = viewModel.UserName;
                    _sysproCredentials.Password = viewModel.Password;
                }

                var serviceController = new ServiceController(_unitOfWork,
                    new ControlPlanJobProcessor(_sysproService, _sysproCredentials));
                serviceController.ProcessControlPlan(viewModel.ControlPlanId, viewModel.CloseJob, true,
                    User.Identity.GetUserId());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
                return View(viewModel);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Post", new { id = viewModel.ControlPlanId, message = "Successfully posted to Syspro" });
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ControlPlanId)
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306859/the-required-anti-forgery-cookie-requestverificationtoken-is-not-present

Comment: None of those suggestions in that thread helped me. In chrome there are no response cookies in both dev or prod but in dev I do not get an error. I've also tried setting an explicit <machineKey validationKey="...../> in the web.config but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I think your markup is goofing up your form submission.  The `<div>` that is opened inside the `using Html.BeginForm()` but not closed prior to the closing of your using statement could be causing POST issues.  The VS editor typically complains about such occurrences.